# Falha da Recuperação de Fábrica de classes - Console Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, conexão, dll

Tenho uma ´Console Application´ que realiza conexão com o `SQL`. Em outras máquinas a aplicação está funcionando normalmente, mas tem uma que possui a versão `Windows Server Enterprise SP2` que está retornando a seguinte exceção:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Falha na
>   recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com CLSID
>   {443DDDD3-7E78-44C6-865C-7984C9D2B08A} devido ao seguinte erro:
>   80040154 Classe não registrada (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).    em
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

A aplicação está sendo compilada para `X86`, que é a versão do `S.O` e `.Net 4.5.2` que está instalada no servidor, conforme ilustra a imagem abaixo:

Ao tentar registrar a classe `System.Data.dll` com o `regsvr32`tem-se a seguinte saída:

> O módulo "System.Data.dll" foi carregado, mas o ponto de entrada não foi
>   encontrado.\n\nCertifique-se de que "System.Data.dll" é um DLL válido ou arquivo
>   OCX e tente novamente

**Código de conexão**

```
var cnx = ""DATA SOURCE=IPSERVER;INITIAL CATALOG=DBNAME; INTEGRATED SECURITY=FALSE;USER ID=USERID;PASSWORD=PASSWDUSER;MULTIPLEACTIVERESULTSETS=TRUE; POOLING=FALSE";";

var conn = new SqlConnection(cnx);

conn.Open();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: System.Data.dll é uma assembly do Framework, você não deve registrar usando `regsvr32`. Com o Framework instalado ela estará acessível. Você procurou no registro pela entra com o CLSID da mensagem de erro? Como você disse que seu SO é 32bits (x86), a chvae deve provavelmente estar em HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{443DDDD3-7E78-44C6-865C-7984C9D2B08A}

Comment: Melhor reparar a instalação do .net: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/install/repair e lembrar de desligar antes todos os serviços não-essenciais do Windows

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server geralmente é x64. O ideal seria você compilar sua aplicação para AnyCPU. Acredito que desta maneira não vai gerar exception.